# jekyll/liquid does not parse key/value dicts in page preamble on github pages

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I have a file `test.md`:

```
---
layout: test
item: {"label":"value"}
---

This text should not appear
```

and a corresponding file `_layouts/test.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Hello world!</h1>
  The field <em>label</em> has value <em>{{ page.item.label }}</em>.
</body>
</html>
```

On my local server I get, as expected, the following page in `_site/test.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Hello world!</h1>
  The field <em>label</em> has value <em>value</em>.
</body>
</html>
```

while on github (see http://altomani.github.com/test.html) the result is:

```html
<p>This text should not appear</p>
```

Comment: I could not find it documented anywhere on github site. Is there some way to read a dict in github's liquid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I couldn’t reproduce the problem, I would suggest you to follow the guidelines and use `yaml` in preambles rather than dicts:

```
---
layout : test
item : 
  label : value
---
```

This should definitely work.

Comment: Still no idea why liquid understands json notation for yaml on my local machine but not on github... The workaround fixed the problem anyway.

Comment: Okay, this is kind of a stale response, but do you notice a difference between running `jekyll serve` and `bundle exec jekyll serve` (with WEBrick)

Comment: Of course I do. `jekyll serve` runs with system-wide gemset, while `bundle exec jekyll serve` runs with local bundle.