# array in config parsed different from local and server

Tags: ruby, yaml, jekyll, github-pages

I have the following in my `_config.yml`:

```
slides: [1,2,3]
```

Then I iterate over it on my view:

```
{% for i in site.slides %}
  // dummy slide
{% endfor %}
```

It works fine on my local dev machine, the dummy slide is shown thrice, but on github pages it's only shown once. Do you guys know why? Could this be a version problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very “strict” version of YAML parser there on github. The almost same question [was already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916854/jekyll-liquid-does-not-parse-key-value-dicts-in-page-preamble-on-github-pages/14917463#14917463).

I would suggest you to use the standard YAML notation for arrays:

```
slides:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd contend that "broken" is a better description than "strict" if this is indeed the behaviour of github's YAML parser.  The [YAML specification](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2790088) very clearly allows the `slides: [1,2,3]` form.

Comment: AFAIK, [there were](http://yaml.org/spec/1.0/#id2489726) _block_ sequences and _flow_ sequences in earlier specs of YAML. I would call the constraint on allowed language constructs the “restriction”/“limitation” rather than a “bug”. E. g., the HTML spec clearly allows `summary`/`details` tags, but who dares to admit that Firefox has a _broken_ HTML support :-) Anyway, block notation talks while flow one walks—that’s it.